# Google Cloud "click to deploy wordpress" VM instance admin not accessible after changing siteurl and home in wp-options table

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, google-cloud-platform, sftp

I am posting this here after a discussion elsewhere.

(https://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-not-access-website-after-changing-the-siteurl-and-home-entries-of-wp_options/#post-10665725)

I am not able to access my site admin page after changing the url in siteurl and home entries in wp-options. The site is http://caid.org.au/ and when I try http://caid.org.au/wp-admin it does not work.

The site is hosted in GCE and also goes through cloudflare, which I have paused at the moment because I could not access the website at all when it was on. The website started working after turning SSL off.

I have tried FTP and ssh and even MySQL workbench but can not access the table so that I can change the settings back to original.

Is there a way to do that?

I'll be really very greatful if this can be resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

its due to HTTPS issue, please set correct SSL links in wp-options

your wp-admin is redirecting to https://

please double check you have SSL certificate installed, then you can use https://caid.org.au/wp-admin/

else you have to use http://caid.org.au/wp-admin/

Comment: Hi! Thanks for a quick response but the problem is I can not access wp-admin. If you can help me with accessing that, that'll be great.

Comment: please try hosting support in order to fix SSL, its purely a SSL issue. and double check you have added the SSL redirection in cloudfare, like https:// in cloudfare